# wp8.1 get fast info of local deleted photos

Tags: local-storage, windows-phone-8.1

Is there a way to get informed by the system if a photo is deleted in the windows phone photolibrary. Or can I scan the Localstorage if there is something deleted without opnening every file?

Thanx
newone

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a clean way to do this on Windows Phone.

In a Windows Runtime app you could use a [FolderQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.search.storagefolderqueryresult.aspx) and then register for its [ContentsChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.search.storagefolderqueryresult.contentschanged.aspx) notification, but these classes aren't available on the phone.